# Managing JDBC connections

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm learning programming and I still can't understand how to manage a system with too many **JDBC** connections. Do I have to open a new connection every time I have a query, or I can create a global connection object and re-use it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+connection+pooling

Answer (score 1):

You should look at connection pools - these allow you to manage the number of connections you have to a database.  The connection pool will (or should) also handle things like closing stale connections, keeping the connections alive while not in use, etc.

A good place to start is [HikariCP](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/) but a whole bunch of others are available.

Comment: Great, you very much Steve :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use DataSource to get your connection. Some DataSource implementations supports connection pooling.

Refer to JDBC documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. Do you think this way it's better than using Connection Pools?